# URLDecoding requests

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests, urlencode

I am trying to get the original url from `requests`. Here is what I have so far:

```
res = requests.get(...)
url = urllib.unquote(res.url).decode('utf8')
```

I then get an error that says:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 60-61: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The original url I requested is:

```
https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/store/movies/american-pie-pr\xc3\xa4sentiert-nackte-tatsachen/8d6kgwzl63ql
```

And here is what happens when I try printing:

```
>>> print '111', res.url
111 https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/store/movies/american-pie-pr%C3%A4sentiert-nackte-tatsachen/8d6kgwzl63ql
>>> print '222', urllib.unquote( res.url )
222 https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/store/movies/american-pie-prÃ¤sentiert-nackte-tatsachen/8d6kgwzl63ql
>>> print '333', urllib.unquote(res.url).decode('utf8') 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 60-61: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is this occurring, and how would I fix this?

Comment: which operation system do you use?

Comment: Seems the OP duplicated this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477799/urllib-unquote-not-properly-decoding-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters
```

You are trying to decode a string that is Unicode already. It raises `AttributeError` on Python 3 (unicode string has no `.decode()` method there). Python 2 tries to *encode* the string into bytes first using `sys.getdefaultencoding()` (`'ascii'`) before passing  it to `.decode('utf8')` which leads to `UnicodeEncodeError`.

In short, **do not call `.decode()` on Unicode strings**, use this instead:

```
print urllib.unquote(res.url.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')
```

---

Without `.decode()` call, the code prints bytes (assuming a bytestring is passed to `unquote()`) that may lead to mojibake if the character encoding used by your environment is not utf-8. To avoid mojibake, **always print Unicode** (don't print *text* as bytes), do not hardcode the character encoding of your environment inside your script  i.e., `.decode()` is necessary here.

---

[There is a bug in `urllib.unquote()` if you pass it a Unicode string](http://bugs.python.org/issue8136):

```
>>> print urllib.unquote(u'​%C3%A4')
Ã¤
>>> print urllib.unquote('​%C3%A4') # utf-8 output
ä
```

**Pass bytestrings to `unquote()` on Python 2.**

Comment: `type(urllib.unquote("https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/store/movies/american-pie-pr%C3%A4sentiert-nackte-tatsachen/8d6kgwzl63ql"))` == `<type 'str'>`. I think the problem is with his locale

Comment: Doesn't matter surely.  The OP doesn't get an exception from `urllib.unquote( res.url )` and I don't get an exception if I use a Unicode: `urllib.unquote(u"https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/store/movies/american-pie-‌​pr%C3%A4sentiert-nackte-tatsachen/8d6kgwzl63ql")`

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: there are 3 separate issues here. And the solution that fixes all 3 issues is to `.encode()` and then `.decode()` as shown in the answer. `type(res.url)` is unicode in the question otherwise we won't see `UnicodeEncodeError` and [`urllib.unquote()` is broken for unicode urls](http://bugs.python.org/issue8136).

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I got the wrong end of the stick :)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: don't apologize for this, I'm grateful for the feedback. Everybody make mistakes, [here's my recent brain failure.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33641463/4279)